# What is replacement of __attribute__ in ISO C standard?

Tags: c, attributes, iso

What is the replacement of `__attribute__` in ISO C standard?
I want to port my software which is compiler independent.

Comment: Most things people do with `__attribute__` are either very wrong and non-portable (packing/alignment/etc.) or just optimizations that are of course unnecessary and can simply be removed to make the code portable. In the former case you need to fix the much larger non-portability issue; just removing `__attribute__` is the easy part.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't one.

One solution is to abstract the attributes behind macros. e.g.:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define UNUSED __attribute((unused))__
#else
#define UNUSED
#endif

...

void function(void) UNUSED;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no general replacement for the wide range of facilities that this gcc extension offers. Most other compilers that are not gcc compatible use `#pragma` to achieve similar goals. Since C99, C has the `_Pragma` operator that allows you to spew pragmas in the middle of your code (not only on proper lines) and to compose the contents of a pragma with macros. But then you still have to do specific "translations" of individual features to the corresponding pragma syntax of your target compiler.

Answer (score 0):

C23 has introduced [attribute specifier sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes), namely these attributes:

```c
[[deprecated]]
[[deprecated("reason")]]
[[fallthrough]]
[[nodiscard]]
[[nodiscard("reason")]]
[[maybe_unused]]
[[noreturn]]
[[_Noreturn]]
[[unsequenced]]
[[reproducible]]
```

You can use the macro `__has_c_attribute` to detect the availability of these attributes:

```c
#if defined(__has_c_attribute)
    /* They are available. Further do: */
    #if __has_c_attribute(deprecated)
    /* to check for the availability of individual attributes. */
```

To consolidate ISO C's and GNU C's attributes, I often do something like this:

```
#if defined(__has_c_attribute)
    #if __has_c_attribute(fallthrough)
        #define ATTRIB_FALLTHROUGH        [[fallthrough]]
    #endif
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define ATTRIB_FALLTHROUGH            __attribute__((fallthrough))
#else 
    #define ATTRIB_FALLTHROUGH            /**/
#endif 

#if !defined(ATTRIB_FALLTHROUGH)
    #define ATTRIB_FALLTHROUGH            /**/
#endif
```

In cases where a compiler does not yet support ISO C's attributes but does support GNU C's attributes, the macro will expand to utilize GNU C's `fallthrough` attribute. Otherwise, it will expand to nothing.